# Stripe redirectToCheckout - “TypeError: stripe.redirectToCheckout is not a function” Rails

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, stripe-payments, checkout

I have a syntax problem I guess but I cannot find why:

in my show.html.erb file, where I want to redirect to checkout:

```
 <script>
    const paymentButton = document.getElementById('pay');
    paymentButton.addEventListener('click', () => {
      const stripe = '<%= Rails.configuration.stripe[:publishable_key]%>';
      stripe.redirectToCheckout({
        sessionId: '<%=@order.checkout_session_id %>'
      });
    });
  </script>
```

In my stripe.rb :

```
if Rails.env.production?
Rails.configuration.stripe = {
  publishable_key: ENV['STRIPE_PUBLISHABLE_KEY'],
  secret_key:      ENV['STRIPE_SECRET_KEY'],
  signing_secret:  ENV['STRIPE_WEBHOOK_SECRET_KEY']
  }
else
  Rails.configuration.stripe = {
    publishable_key: ENV['STRIPE_PUBLISHABLE_TEST_KEY'],
    secret_key:      ENV['STRIPE_SECRET_TEST_KEY'],
    signing_secret:  ENV['STRIPE_WEBHOOK_SECRET_TEST_KEY']
  }
end
```

The redirection to stripe checkout doesn't work with :

```
const stripe = '<%= Rails.configuration.stripe[:publishable_key]%>';
```

Although everything works perfectly with this:

```
const stripe = Stripe('<%= ENV['STRIPE_PUBLISHABLE_KEY'] %>');
```

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`const stripe = '<%= Rails.configuration.stripe[:publishable_key]%>';`

This line is assigning the publishable key to a string constant.

`const stripe = Stripe('<%= ENV['STRIPE_PUBLISHABLE_KEY'] %>');`

This line is initializing an instance of Stripe.js passing the publishable key.

Assuming the configuration is correct and `Rails.configuration.stripe[:publishable_key]` contains the publishable key, (you can check this in the console or logging it out with the `Rails.logger`) you likely want:

`var stripe = Stripe('<%= Rails.configuration.stripe[:publishable_key] %>');`